# How to manually add a boxplot in a pre-existing ggplot2 line plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, combinedchart

I create a line plot with ggplot with the following data and code:

```
dat<-read.table(text= 
  "2019            2641.621           2613.385
  2020            2633.569           2605.428
  2021            2656.257           2627.863
  2022            2668.704           2640.147
  2023            2647.242           2618.982
  2024            2662.498           2634.032")

ggplot(dat, aes(x = V1))+
  
  geom_line(aes(y= V2),col="red") +
  geom_line(aes(y = V3),col="blue")
```

The resulting plot:

[image]

Now, I want to manually add a boxplot at x = 2025 by specifying boxplot values that I have previously calculated and are not in a data frame. I insert the code for the boxplot at the end:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = V1))+
  
  geom_line(aes(y= V2),col="red") +
  geom_line(aes(y = V3),col="blue") +
  
  geom_boxplot(
    stat = "identity",
    aes(x=2025,
        lower  = 2312.8,
        upper  = 2394.3,
        middle = 2343.5,
        ymin   = 2254.8,
        ymax   = 2440.4))
```

I get the following error:

Error in `geom_boxplot()`:
! Problem while converting geom to grob.
ℹ Error occurred in the 5th layer.
Caused by error in `draw_group()`:
! Can only draw one boxplot per group
ℹ Did you forget `aes(group = ...)`?

I tried with geom_pointrange, and it does work:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = V1))+
  
  geom_line(aes(y= V2),col="red") +
  geom_line(aes(y = V3),col="blue") +
  geom_pointrange(aes(x=2025,y=2343.5,ymax=2394.3,ymin=2312.8),col="red")
```

[image]

But this is not what I want. How can I get the boxplot instead?

Comment: `geom_xxx` functions typically have an `inherit.aes` argument which can trip the unwary.  To create your boxplot, try `... + geom_boxplot(data=<yourboxplotdataframe>, inherit.aes=FALSE, ...)`.  It's difficult to be more precise because your question is neither reproducible (you haven't given us test data) nor minimal (fills and colours are not relevant to the question).  Also, I would avoid `limits` in a `scale` function.  That can have undesiravle and confusing side effects.  `coord_cartesian` is much safer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Limey, I simplified the code and provided test data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
ggplot()+geom_boxplot(data = data.frame(aux = c(2312.8,2394.3,2343.5,2254.8,2440.4)),
    aes(x=2110, y = aux))
```

If you create an `auxiliar` object, R can create the boxplot by itself without passing the other arguments. Also, try

```
ggplot()+geom_boxplot(data = data.frame(aux = c(2312.8,2394.3,2343.5,2254.8,2440.4)),
    aes(x=2110, y = aux), width = 10)
```

in order to increase its width and make it easier to see.